# Spark executors as best effort pods

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Does anyone know if it's possible to run spark executors as best effort pods on kubernetes?
It looks like the cpu/memory requests would be set to some default value, even if a pod template is used.
If not possible, where are those defaults being set in the spark codebase.

Comment: If the CPU/memory requests are set automatically, you probably have the [LimitRanger](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#limitranger) admission controller active (configured with a LimitRange object) or some other admission controller. Did you check this?

Comment: @weibeld I'm able to create other best effort pods. I'm pretty sure pods created by spark are getting their properties populated according to the table [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties).